# Convertir un string en un nuevo string

Tags: php, string

El objetivo de este ejercicio es convertir un string en una nuevo string donde cada caracter del nuevo string es `"("` si ese caracter aparece solo una vez en la cadena original, o `")"` si ese caracter aparece más de una vez en el string original. Se deberán ignorar las mayúsculas para determinar si un caracter está repetido o no.

Ejemplos:

```
"din"      =>  "((("
"recede"   =>  "()()()"
"Success"  =>  ")())())"
" ( ( )"   =>  ")))))("
```

El problema de mi programa consiste en que los caracteres `"("` y `")"` son tomados como si fueran un solo caracter repetido. En lugar de obtener

```
" ( ( )"     =>  ")))))("
```

obtengo

```
" ( ( )"     =>  "))))))"
```

He aquí mi propuesta de programa:

```
function duplicate_encode($word)
{
        for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($word) - 1; $i++) {
            $word = (substr_count(strtolower($word),$word[$i]) == 1) ? str_replace($word[$i],'(',$word) : str_replace($word[$i],')',$word);
        }
        return $word;
}
echo duplicate_encode($word);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás modificando la cadena y usando a la vez **un carácter que es parte de la cadena** como indicativo de repetición, si usas otro tipo de caracter verás que funciona, por ejemplo:

```
$word = (substr_count(strtolower($word),$word[$i]) == 1) ? str_replace($word[$i],'|',$word) : str_replace($word[$i],'_',$word);
```

Ahí tendrás el resultado:

```
_____|
```

Puedes modificar la función así, si quieres usar los paréntesis. Aquí funciona porque trabajamos sobre una nueva cadena que vamos modificando, al final la retornamos:

```
function duplicate_encode($word)
{
    $s="";
        for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($word) - 1; $i++) {

            $s.= (substr_count(strtolower($word),$word[$i]) == 1) ? "(" : ")";
        }
        return $s;
}
```

O bien de este modo:

```
function duplicate_encode($word) {
    $array = str_split($word);
    $s="";
    foreach ($array as $char) {
        $s.= substr_count($word,$char)===1 ? "(" : ")";
    }
    return $s;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
)))))(
```